# image paste problem while using pillow - python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When i trying to use this code, the output is coming a full black image:

```
img = Image.open("image.png")
font = ImageFont.truetype("ArialCE.ttf", size)
text = Image.new(mode = "RGBA", size= (400,375))

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(new_image)
text = input_text
draw.text((x,y), text, (0,0,0), font = font)
text.save("saved.png")
img.paste(text, (0,0))
img.save("text.png")
```

i am using pillow library, i want the "text" image to be pasted on the img.

thanks

Comment: You are drawing black text on a black image...

Comment: i think RGBA supports alpha?? i have written that text image to be a RGBA??

Comment: `Image.new()` creates a black image by defauit... https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.new

Comment: Why are you creating a new image, drawing text on it and then pasting onto the background? Why not just draw text straight on the background?

Comment: i am doing this because i wanna rotate the image with the text

Comment: Ok, I see. That part is not mentioned in your question. Try initialising your image to be transparent with a 4-tuple of RGBA values as the last parameter to `Image.new()`.

Comment: with this: ```new_image = Image.new(mode = "RGBA", size= (400,375), tuple=4)``` this error is coming: ```new() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tuple'``` :(

Comment: ops, pls see the edits in my last message

Comment: No, i am stilling getting that problem. still thanks that you given me time to answer my question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a transparent image, use [Image.new()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.new) like this:

```
im = Image.new('RGBA', (640,480), color=(0,0,0,0))
```